# Mini bike gets speed then eventually shuts off

Tags: mini-bike

It starts fine then once I get about full throttle, it will slow down and shake real rough. Then eventually come to a stop then shut off, but it turns on fine after. What could this be and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It sounds to me like a fueling problem, where the carburetor (assuming it is carbureted) isn't getting all the fuel it needs to do the job. When sitting, the bowl can fill up, but then once running, it goes through the fuel faster then can be resupplied.

Comment: What can I do to fix this?

Comment: As a guess? You *might* be able to run something like SeaFoam through your carb at a high concentrate. If that doesn't work after a tank full and you are capable, you could rebuild the carb. If not, most carbs for small engines are fairly cheap.  I'm pretty sure the problem lies in the carb, but not for sure.